# Obtain path between concepts in Wordnet

Tags: path, wordnet

[image: A segment of Wordnet]

I want to find the semantic similarity between two concepts in Wordnet, for eg. between two concepts 'novelist' and 'communicator'. I need to find the shortest path connecting these two concepts and then obtain the concepts in the shortest path between ‘novelist’ and ‘communicator’ (i.e., ‘novelist-author- communicator’).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to semantic similarity using WordNet has been proposed in the paper "Sentence Similarity based on Semantic Nets and Corpus Statistics" by Li, et al. and implemented by [sujitpal](https://github.com/sujitpal/nltk-examples/blob/master/src/semantic/short_sentence_similarity.py) in Python. I believe this is what you could start with.